# Amazon sns firebase analytics label

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I'm able to send and create firebase analytics label using firebase REST:

[image]

However, how can I do it in Amazon SNS (which is connected to firebase)?

```
{
  "GCM":"{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \"BobyTest\", \"title\":\"TitleTest\" } }"
}
```

I've tried:

```
{
  "GCM":"{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \"BobyTest\", \"title\":\"TitleTest\" },\"fcm_options\": {\"analytics_label\":\"testAnalyticsLabel\"}}\" }"
}
```

Able to receive the push notification but the analytics label is not created.

Tried to refer to [SNS docs - sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html), the list of the key-value pairs documents is referring to the [legacy API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref):

[image]

Noticed the "fcm_options" is only available in the new API:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this using SNS? I need the analytics label to filter the data in the cloud messaging report:

[image]